# jQuery form plugin works in Firefox & IE, but adds an invalid ID to webkit forms?

Tags: jquery, debugging, forms, attributes, webkit

I have a very strange issue that only affects webkit browsers for some reason, I have written a little jQuery form plugin that takes care of validation and applies state classes for easy css styling but it does not touch the form `id` attribute.

However in Safari 5 and Google Chrome for Mac the form is being assigned `id="[object HTMLInputElement]"` which breaks the form…

I have tried isolating the issue by commenting out lines of the jQuery plugin but this didn't get me anywhere.

I also seem to have found that by removing the following line from a bunch of CMS (ExpressionEngine) generated hidden fields fixes this issue:

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="freeform" />`

but for obvious reasons I cannot remove that line from the code (generated by cms) also if I leave the line in the source and disable my script it also does not break so it seems to be a specific issue with that line of html, my plugin and webkit.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have already spend close to a day trying this thing out but can't seem to fix it.

Here is a jsFiddle I have setup that shows this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jannis/5CMdP/

It works fine in non-webkit but in webkit when looking at the form in the bottom right output frame you'll notice the form having the invalid id attribute.

Thanks for checking this out.

Much appreciated.

Jannis

Comment: Copying the code from your fiddle into a standalone example appears to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a 1.4.3 bug, see here:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7212

(Bug) find() to fail when selecting from forms containing inputs named “id”

Sound familiar? :)

See here for a patch if you want to keep using 1.4.3 (its in sizzle):

https://github.com/jeresig/sizzle/commit/b758239

Comment: Can you explain how to patch jquery 1.4.3 min file with sizzle?

Comment: @so1o, that sizzle repo seems to have disappeared from the internet, so your best bet may be to just upgrade your jQuery to the newest version and see if it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's a bug in the version of jQuery the fiddle is using. Switching to 1.4.4 fixes the problem.